# An application of the stochastic dominance property

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, improper-integrals, lebesgue-measure, expected-value

Assume that $U \sim $ uniform$[0, 1]$. Let $f$ be the function defined on $[0, 1]$ by
$f(x) = 1(x > U)$, where $1(.)$ is the indicator function.

For any $U \ne x$, $1(x > U)$ is derivable in $x$ and the derivative is zero. I can then say that the derivative $f'(x)$ exists almost surely. I am interested in $\mathbb{E}(f'(x))$, where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation taken with respect to $U$.

I know that $\mathbb{E}(f(x)) = x$. So, $\partial \mathbb{E}(f(x))/ \partial x = 1$. How can I apply stochastic dominance here? That is, how to show that $\mathbb{E}(f'(x)) = 1$?

Comment: If $f'(x)=0$ almost surely, then $\mathbb E[f'(x)]=0$.

Comment: The derivative is the dirac delta.

Answer (score 1):

> For any $U≠x, \mathbf 1(x>U)$ is derivable in x and the derivative is zero.

The issue is that you are deriving across the point where $U=x$, where the indicator has a step discontinuity, and is not *technically* derivable.

Rather the derivative of a Step Impulse function is considered to be the [Dirac Delta](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html), a generalised function.

$\qquad\begin{align} \dfrac{\partial \mathbf 1_{(x>u)}}{\partial x} &= \delta_{(x-u)}  \\[2ex]\mathsf E\big(f(x)\big) & =\int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm d u \\[1ex]&= \int_0^1 \mathbf 1_{(x>u)}\,\mathrm d u \\[1ex]&= \int_{0}^{\min\{1, \max\{0,x\}\}}\,\mathrm d u \\[1ex] &= x\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\lt 1} + \mathbf 1_{1\leqslant x}
\\[2ex] \mathsf E\big(f'(x)\big) &=\int_0^1 f'(x) \,\mathrm d u \\[1ex]&= \int_0^1 \delta_{(x-u)} \,\mathrm d u \\[1ex]&= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}
\end{align}$